# Unix find command - Equivalent of .net File.Exists and Directoty.Exists in Unix

Tags: unix, find

In our .net application we have to run file operation commands against Unix system. I am trying to have equivalent of File.Exists and Directory.Exists.

Using ssh in in .net, got to work so far in following way:

Find only files with matching name:

```
find /folder/subfolder -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname test.mov
```

Find only directories with matching name:

```
find /folder/subfolder -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname test
```

Question - Is it possible to do above operations without splitting full path?

It is not big deal to split the path but existing service in production accepts only command to run and the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test -d  /path/to/directory_name  
[ -d /path/to/directory_name  ]
```

return true or false - i.e. directory.exists

```
test -f /path/to/filename
[ -f /path/to/filename ]
```

same for files

You can use these constructs to return ok or not ok

```
[ -f /path/to/filename ]  && exit 0 || exit 1
```

find does not return an error when it cannot find a named directory or file